# doubly linked list, i can seem to create a new Node, How far off am i?

Tags: c++, nodes, doubly-linked-list

the program is suppose to be a doubly linked list that prompts the user to either

> ```
> 1.Insert"
> "2. Delete"<<endl<<
> "3. Display"<<endl<<
> "4. Sum"<<endl<<
> "5. Average"<<endl<<
> "6. Exit"
> From the list above what would you like to do next?"
> ```

problem: at execution, after i enter a double for "value", the program freeze for a little bit then exits

//-- input prompt

> ```
> cout<<"\nWhat value would you like to insert to the list: ";
> cin>>value;
> l.insertAtEnd(value);
> break;
> ```

//--- function definition ---

> ```
> void List::insertAtEnd(double & x)
>     {   
>         List::NodePointer ptr;
>
>         ptr = new List::Node(last, x );
>         last->next = ptr;
>         last = ptr;
>         count ++;
>         sum += x;
>     }
> ```

//--- prototypes

> ## include

```
    // #include"Node.h" 
>     
>     using namespace std;
>     
>     #ifndef LIST
>     #define LIST
>     
>     typedef double ElementType;
>     
>     class List
>     {
>         public:
>             ...
>             void insertAtEnd(ElementType & x); //insert a value x on the end of the list
>             ...
>         
>     private:
>             ...
>             
>             class Node
>             {
>                 public:
>                 ElementType data;
>                 Node *prev;
>                 Node *next;
>                 //--- Node constructor
>                 /*-------------------------------------------------------------------
>                     Precondition:  None.
>                     Postcondition: A Node has been constructed with value in its data 
>                         part and its next part set to link (default 0).
>                     -------------------------------------------------------------------*/
>                 Node(Node *prevNodePtr,ElementType value, Node *link = 0)
>     
>                     : prev(prevNodePtr) ,data(value), next(link)
>                 {}
>             };
>     
>             typedef Node * NodePointer;
>             NodePointer last;
>             NodePointer first;
>     
>     };
>     
>     ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const List & s);
>     
>     #endif // !LIST
```

please help...

Comment: The chances for you to get help increase dramatically if you produce an [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Unless this is a pure learning exercise, you really want [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). If it is, then a basic insert and removal example would be [Doubly-Linked List of Integers](https://pastebin.com/E6WpPjTC)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin ... or ... *no list at all*.

Comment: it is a learning assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are far off. The main problem I see is that you don't deal with the `first` pointer in your `List` class.

When you are adding a value to the end of a list like this the first value to be added to the list is a special case because you must also update the `first` pointer. Your code doesn't do this.

The other unusual thing about your code is that you have those `count` and `sum` variables. It seems like you are trying to keep a running total of the list length and list sum. That's not wrong but it's an unusual thing to do. Normally you would calculate those when needed, not all the time. Also if you do keep doing things that way then you need to add `count` and `sum` to your list class. At the moment you have a list in one variable and it's length and sum in different variables. That's bad design because there's no close association between the variables. Imagine you had two lists. How would you keep the `count` and `sum` variables updated then? Personally I would just remove the code dealing with `count` and `sum`, just calculate these quantities when you need them.

Comment: I added the following to, i hope, handle the first vs last 

void List::insertAtEnd(double & x)
{   
    if (first == 0)
    {
        first = new List::Node(last, x  );
    }else
    {
        last->next = new List::Node(last, x  );
    }
    
}

i also added a count function to "walk through" the list and add the numbers nodes

@john : your right, i need to keep remembering to modularize code ... practice, practice, practice

Comment: i keep getting these errors:
a value of type "List::Node *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "List::NodePointer"
no instance of constructor "List::Node::Node" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (List::NodePointer, double)

referencing:

first = new List::Node(last, x  );

and

Comment: @raven065 Not sure without seeing the latest code. Speaking personally again, I would not use the `NodePointer` typedef, pointers are tricky, it's better to be completely explicit about their use, not hiding them behind a typedef (even when it's well named like yours). So maybe removing the `NodePointer` typedef will help clear up what this error is about.